# angular (click) is not calling function in loop

Tags: angular, angular5

i am trying to crate a table with a cell edit functionally. i have an array of cell data. i am iterating the array and crating a button with bootstrap pencil icon. please check below template

```
  <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="awidth row-border hover 
     display table table-bordered striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let key of mycoloums" class="icon-margin" style="padding: 8px;">{{key.displayName}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let gefield of gefields" class=" tab-font-size font-weight ">

    <td  *ngFor="let k of mycoloums"  class="tab-font-size font-weight" >
        <span  (focusout) ="saveDetails($event, gefield, k)">{{gefield[k.data]}}</span>
        <button *ngIf='k.edit == true' class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right white' (click)="makeCellEdit($event)"></button>
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="gefields?.length == 0">
    <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

my function on ts file is

```
CellEdit(e) {console.log("cell edit")}

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'; import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'; import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

class DataTablesResponse {   data: any[];   draw: number;   recordsFiltered: number;   recordsTotal: number;   coloumnName: {}; }

@Component({   selector: 'app-dynamic-datatable',   templateUrl: './dynamic-datatable.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./dynamic-datatable.component.css'] }) export class DynamicDatatableComponent implements OnInit {


 mycoloums =[
    { data: "check", displayName: "check", hyperlink: false, edit: true},
    { data: 'processID',displayName: "Process Id", hyperlink: false, edit: true }, 
    { data: 'processName', displayName: "Process Name", hyperlink: true, edit: true },
    { data: 'processDescription',displayName: "Process Description", hyperlink: true, edit: true}   ];

 gefields = [
    {
        "processID": 1,
        "versionPublishedOnDateTime": null,
        "processLastModifiedOnDateTime": null,
        "processVersion": "",
        "processDescription": "My Process",
        "processLastModifiedByUserID": null,
        "functionID": 1,
        "processName": "My Process"
    },
    {
        "processID": 2,
        "versionPublishedOnDateTime": null,
        "processLastModifiedOnDateTime": null,
        "processVersion": "",
        "processDescription": "My Process 2",
        "processLastModifiedByUserID": null,
        "functionID": 2,
        "processName": "My Process 2"
    },
    {
        "processID": 3,
        "versionPublishedOnDateTime": null,
        "processLastModifiedOnDateTime": null,
        "processVersion": "",
        "processDescription": "map process",
        "processLastModifiedByUserID": null,
        "functionID": 3,
        "processName": "map process"
    },
    {
        "processID": 4,
        "versionPublishedOnDateTime": null,
        "processLastModifiedOnDateTime": null,
        "processVersion": "",
        "processDescription": "dd Process",
        "processLastModifiedByUserID": null,
        "functionID": 3,
        "processName": "dd Process"
    } ];   dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};   showPopUp = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
       }   ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("_____________ngOnInit End____________");
    const that = this;

    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 4,

      columns: this.mycoloums,

    };   }

  makeCellEdit(e) {
    console.log("______makeCellEdit()_____");   } }
```

i am using this table as a child component. but when I clicked on button my function is not calling

please help me.

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: else reproduce your problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bifxrx

Comment: can you please paste the entire code as is? Because from what I see there seem to be spelling mistakes - "conlose.log() instead of console.log()"

Comment: @prodeep no I am not getting any error on console

Comment: Also your HTML is wrong. Your id keeps repeating. Obviously the event will not fire.

Comment: @binDebug I change the spelling but same issue

Comment: <button id ="editPencil" <- This ID will keep repeating for every cell. How will the event fire?

Comment: I am not doing anything with Id, i removed it

Comment: as per @binDebug , code seems fine except spelling mistakes, better is you post your full code to solve it faster

Comment: yes I am trying to upload on stackblitz.com. but its a first time me. so i am getting some import error

Comment: no worries @user3364549 either you can post your files here too https://justpaste.it/

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` after your `button`. Delete that and try again

Comment: yes removed but no success... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got your concern, the actual problem is your grid. if you are playing with Jquery then you have to stick with that. it is not a good idea to use both jquery and angular togther.

angular is very mature it self. any ways if you want to call a function from a grid you have to deal with jquery function on click

```
 $("#yourselector").click(function(){
    makeCellEdit();
});
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This stackblitz has the working code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m9tudm?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';  
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

class DataTablesResponse {   data: any[];   draw: number;   recordsFiltered: number;   recordsTotal: number;   coloumnName: {}; }

@Component({   selector: 'app-dynamic-datatable',   templateUrl: './hello.component.html'}) 
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {

 mycoloums =[
    { data: "check", displayName: "check", hyperlink: false, edit: true},
    { data: 'processID',displayName: "Process Id", hyperlink: false, edit: true }, 
    { data: 'processName', displayName: "Process Name", hyperlink: true, edit: true },
    { data: 'processDescription',displayName: "Process Description", hyperlink: true, edit: true}   ];

 gefields = [
    {
        "processID": 1,
        "versionPublishedOnDateTime": null,
        "processLastModifiedOnDateTime": null,
        "processVersion": "",
        "processDescription": "My Process",
        "processLastModifiedByUserID": null,
        "functionID": 1,
        "processName": "My Process"
    },
    {
        "processID": 2,
        "versionPublishedOnDateTime": null,
        "processLastModifiedOnDateTime": null,
        "processVersion": "",
        "processDescription": "My Process 2",
        "processLastModifiedByUserID": null,
        "functionID": 2,
        "processName": "My Process 2"
    },
    {
        "processID": 3,
        "versionPublishedOnDateTime": null,
        "processLastModifiedOnDateTime": null,
        "processVersion": "",
        "processDescription": "map process",
        "processLastModifiedByUserID": null,
        "functionID": 3,
        "processName": "map process"
    },
    {
        "processID": 4,
        "versionPublishedOnDateTime": null,
        "processLastModifiedOnDateTime": null,
        "processVersion": "",
        "processDescription": "dd Process",
        "processLastModifiedByUserID": null,
        "functionID": 3,
        "processName": "dd Process"
    } ];   
   
    showPopUp = false;

  constructor() {
       }   ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("_____________ngOnInit End____________");
    const that = this;

    }

  makeCellEdit(e) {
    console.log("______makeCellEdit()_____");   } }
```

Component Code:

```html
 <table datatable class="awidth row-border hover 
     display table table-bordered striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let key of mycoloums" class="icon-margin" style="padding: 8px;">{{key.displayName}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let gefield of gefields" class=" tab-font-size font-weight ">

    <td  *ngFor="let k of mycoloums"  class="tab-font-size font-weight" >
        
        <button *ngIf='k.edit == true' class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right white' (click)="makeCellEdit($event)">{{k.displayName}}</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="gefields?.length == 0">
    <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Let me edit the answer to copy the code as is, but stackblitz should work for you.

Comment: i am not dealing with ID. and i am new in angular and stackblitz, so not able to upload the code

Comment: please check the updated question. all the imports  and updated code are there.

Comment: Can you please add the code for DataTables? The dtOptions

Comment: its a simple data table with pagination. i just added by the command

Comment: yes your code is working. but the problem is when you will add   <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"  class="awidth row-border hover display table table-bordered striped">  then only it will not work

Comment: datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"